# Typescript: exclude values from possible keys

Tags: typescript

I have a nested data structure, and I would like to differentiate nested values from leaf values.

```
interface Leaf {
   isOk: boolean
}
type ExcludedKeys = Exclude<string, keyof Leaf>;
interface Node {
  [key: not in ExcludedKeys]: Node | Leaf
}

// this is valid
const okay = { foo: { bar: { isOk: true }, zed: { isOk: true} }}
// this is not, because isOK key only appears in leafs
const failing = { isOk: { foo: { isOk: true } } }
```

This may have been asked already but I can't find duplicates.

The `not in EcludedKeys` does not exist but it summerize what I try to achieve.

Any idea how I could implement this?

I can tweak the data structure a little but it is currently optimal for consumption, I can write `get(myObject, "foo.bar.isOk", false)` to access a leaf very easily for instance.

Example usage:

```
console.log(okay.foo.bar)
okay.foo.bar.isOk = false
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPksUgJbAAuEATgGYLIAyEIteRJnpUA8gNYAuJACMA9qIwtgHYgF8ZZSjXqIkAOVEATZBAAeVYJqhIACiGoVSmADwAlCPFHVN1vhACeots1YAaJMAQAG40AHyh7JycANqCSFAU1OQA5gC6QhraSAA+SD5suQCuhhC05BCaCvIKjsAJSKJ8IO4ZWsgAvHhItOJCuCLmfWS8cYmFyLL+WBVD3PxCYxNIsss1onUUA5qtWZ39c3H9PaKzIwvU48tX1bJAA) work for you (check it against your use cases)? If so I'll write it up as an answer; if not, please modify the question with relevant info.

Comment: You seem to at least have fixed the issue on object creation, however I've added some read/write operations, they do not seem to work because "isOk" may be `undefined`. I hoped that TS could guess that "okay.foo" is a Node and "okay.foo.bar.isOk" means that it's a leaf.

Comment: `okay.foo` could be a `Leaf` because object types in TypeScript are open, not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), so `okay.foo.bar` might well exist even if `okay.foo` is a `Leaf`.  You might want to explicitly change your tree structure to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) where you have a common property like `nodeType` set to `"Leaf"` for leaves and `"Node"` for nodes, and then check against that.

Comment: You are right that makes sense. I don't want to use a discriminating field, so in my case it should probably be fine to cast objects explicitly (I know when I require a Node or a Leaf)